# Upload files as virtual without saved on server using Owl-Carousel as small slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

**Hello,**

***firstly***, i'm not excellent in the English,

it's possible, uploaded a files and showing in the small slider using owl-carousel without client-side only(without save anything in the server).

i mean uploaded as virtual, and saved it when click on submit or click on save

```
$('#MyDiv-owl').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 0,
        dots: false,
        rtl: _isRTL ? true : false,
        stagePadding: 25,
        nav: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 5
            }
        }
    });
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iHaJ.jpg)

> Thank you so much, help me, please?

Comment: you can access the uploaded file by `const selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];`

Comment: @JayLi sorry, my problem is not how to access to the files, my problem is how i can upload a files as virtual without visit a server.

Comment: As @JayLi has suggested you can access the selected files which are in effect the "virtual" upload you want. Anything beyond this would be an actually upload to the server. Access the selected files and then display them in "owl-carousel" as you would normally display files using that tool.